# How to find averages of specific elements in a large text file

Tags: python, loops, floating-point, text-files, classification

I'm trying to achieve what the instructions below in the expected output section states. The text file contains 5 floating point numbers per line, with the last one being of no use since it just classifies whether the previous numbers mean it's a real or fake bill (0 being fake, 1 being real). I want to create a loop that can take the first number of each row (there are 600+ rows) and find the average, same with the second number of each row, third, and fourth. The output should be a list that shows each average [avg1 avg2 avg3 avg4]. The code below can successfully do this, but only one at a time. Eg. in this line sum += float(line.split()[0]), changing 0 to 1 will give the average of the second number in each row and so on. How do I create an efficient loop that can give me all the averages at once?

I've already tried copying the loop and pasting it 4 times for each "column" of numbers but its inefficient and doesn't work.

```
import web_scraper
import urllib.request
import math

def data_text_files():

page = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/00267/data_banknote_authentication.txt'
stream = urllib.request.urlopen(page)

samples = web_scraper.get_all_data(stream, ',')

training = open("training2.txt", "w")
testing = open ("testing2.txt", "w")

for i in range(len(samples)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        #write data to training file
        count = 1
        for bill in samples[i]:
            bill_str = str(bill)
            if(count == 5):
                training.write(bill_str + "\n")
                count = 1
            else:
                training.write(bill_str + " ")
                count += 1

    else:
        #write data to testing file
        count = 1
        for bill in samples[i]:
            bill_str = str(bill)
            if(count == 5):
                testing.write(bill_str + "\n")
                count = 1
            else:
                testing.write(bill_str + " ")
                count += 1



data_text_files()



with open('training2.txt') as fh:
    sum = 0  # initialize here, outside the loop
    count = 0  # and a line counter
    for line in fh:
        count += 1  # increment the counter
        sum += float(line.split()[0])  # add here, not in a nested loop


    average = [sum / count]

    print (average)








 building_classifier()
```

Each data sample has 4 attributes (excluding the last one that indicates the classification of the sample).   So, the data looks something like this:

```
  [ [2, 4, 6, 8, 0],
    [4, 6, 8, 10,  0],
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 1]
    [3, 5, 7, 9,  1]]
```

To build the classifier you will use the data in "training.txt":

Calculate the average of each of the attributes across all the samples with the same classification (0 or 1).  For the data shown above, the averages for each attribute across the counterfeit samples (0) are [3, 5, 7, 9]  and for those that are real (1) the averages are [2, 4, 6, 8].
Find the midpoints between the averages for the 2 groups by adding the average of the counterfeit and the average of the real samples and divide the result by two.  This will be done for each of the attributes.  So, for the data shown, the midpoints would be [2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 8.5 ].  The midpoints are what we will use as our classifier.

Comment: Your question is a little too broad. You only need help with getting the average, not the classifier right? Would be helpful if you could post an example of how the input file looks like

Comment: Most of the code in your example doesn't have to do with your question, the problem really only starts at `with open('training2.txt') as fh:`. Also, although that part appears to be correctly indented, the code preceding it isn't, giving everyone trying to understand the problem a hard read - please correct that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, but I can answer this part of it.

"Calculate the average of each of the attributes across all the samples with the same classification"

I would create a dataframe from the file using pandas and then add column headers:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input_file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Then I would use pandas groupby and aggregate methods for each column:

```
aggregate = df.groupby(['e'])
a_column_mean = aggregate.agg({'a': 'mean'})
b_column_mean = aggregate.agg({'b': 'mean'})
c_column_mean = aggregate.agg({'c': 'mean'})
d_column_mean = aggregate.agg({'d': 'mean'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need installed libraries like `pandas`, although they do have easy to use functions to calculate averages for tables.

Your code calculates a single sum and counts the lines and then calculates a single average from that. You want to calculate all four averages in the same loop. You could do this even more easily by reading the entire file in one go, but I'll stick with your approach, since it would matter for exceedingly large files:

```
with open('training2.txt') as fh:
    n = 4  # number of fields we're interested in
    sums = [0] * n  # initialize here, outside the loop
    count = 0  # and a line counter
    for line in fh:
        count += 1  # increment the counter
        fields = line.split()  # split the line outside the loop, only once
        for i in range(n):
            sums[i] += float(fields[i])  # add here, not in a nested loop

    averages = [s / count for s in sums]  # not using the name sum, as it is a built-in

    print(averages)
```

This is assuming your code works and your text file actually has the values separated by spaces, otherwise you'd need something like `.split(',')`